# How to define dependencies between targets in a TemplateInfo.plist file in Xcode 6?

Tags: xcode6

When creating a `TemplateInfo.plist` file to define an Xcode project template that contains multiple targets, it used to be possible to use the `Dependencies` element of a `Target` within the `TemplateInfo.plist` file to create a dependency between that target and other targets.

With the intro of Xcode 6, the `TemplateInfo.plist` `Dependencies` element seems to either have been removed or is broken. Target dependencies are no longer created in the resulting Xcode project template, and even worse, including the `Dependencies` element seems to corrupt other elements contained within the same `TemplateInfo.plist` file.

Has anyone figured out how to define a target dependency within a `TemplateInfo.plist` file under Xcode 6?

Before answering, please note that I am *not* asking for the steps to manually create a dependency between targets in Xcode. I am asking how to do it within one or more `TemplateInfo.plist` files.

Thanks.

Comment: see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26005871/make-a-dependent-target-with-an-xcode-6-template/26046787

Comment: @PaulBeusterien Thanks for coming back here and adding the link to your answer!